# objective function for graph coloring with ORtools solver

Tags: optimization, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat, graph-coloring

i wrote a cp function to solve graph coloring with ORtools

(minimizing color usage, when the colors of every two vertices on an edge needs to be different)
i get weird result,which isnt optimal, and im not sure why- i think my objective function is wrong, or my constraint formulation,any help?
thanks

```py
    def cp_with_ortools(node_count, edge_count, edges, M, solution, max_degree):
        global colors
        from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
        solution = [0] * (node_count)# list of colors to nodes initialized with 0
        # Creates the model.
        model = cp_model.CpModel()

        # Creates the variables.
        for i in range(node_count):
            solution[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, int(node_count), '')
            #shouldnt be max_degree? isnt working..
            
        # Adds  constraint
        for edge in edges:
            model.Add(solution[edge[0]] != solution[edge[1]])

        # Create the objective function
        obj_var = model.NewIntVar(0, node_count, 'makespan')
        model.AddMaxEquality(obj_var,solution)
        model.Minimize(obj_var)

        #model.Minimize(len(set(solution)))
        #model.Minimize(sum(solution)))

        # Creates a solver and solves the model.
        solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

        status = solver.Solve(model)

        if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
            colors = [solver.Value(solution[i]) for i in range(node_count)]

        return colors
```

Comment: `len(set(solution))` is a constant, you could minimize the max value of solutions using `addmaxequality`, or model the problem using booleans

Comment: obj_var = model.NewIntVar(0, node_count, 'makespan')
                                                                                 model.AddMaxEquality(obj_var,solution)
                                                                                                       
model.Minimize(obj_var)

Comment: something like this? because its still not working :/ thanks though

Comment: what is solution? a dict? maybe you need `solution.values()`?

Comment: solution is a list of the colors each node will get, at the beginning its zeros array but  solver is supposed to put a color for each node in every cell-its just an array for vaiables here. colors is reciving the answer from solver - i do get a list, but it isnt optimal. solution isn't accessible, only solver.Value(solution[i]) gives solution values...so i can reach solution.values

Comment: Are you sure it isn't optimal? See: http://www.hakank.org/google_cp_solver/coloring_cp_sat.py

Comment: well unfortunately, I'm not sure, but it doesn't look like my other solutions. With different algorithms that got identical answers, so I don't have any good thing to compare with..